# Efficient change comparisons across networked systems

Tags: design, architecture, rest

## Overview

> I've got 2 systems over a network. The 2nd system produces some results based on the *current contents* of system A. How can I efficiently produce results in system B if getting the contents of system A takes a long time?

### Current sitation

- I've got a system, system A, that keeps customers (personal details, etc). The user can manually enter hits in this system.
- I've got another system, system B, that performs, every night, some checks on each customer. It checks if a customer appears on a restricted-persons list producing a report of hits. A user checks on this system each morning and screens manually the produced hits. If a hit is approved, it is then send via POST for saving into system A.

### The problem

User might have entered a manual hit in System A, which was also found automatically in System B.

### Solution A

> Send a `GET` request to system A, every time I present system's B overnight results to the user, to get the existing hits and filter them out of hits produced by System B

In order to ameliorate this mismatch, every time I present the results of system B in the morning, I can send a GET request to get the existing hits of a customer in System A and then perform a comparison, filtering out hits that exist in A and B's hits.

This allows me to show only the new hits in System B. The user screens only the *new hits* that were found.

#### A problem with this solution

I can't *efficiently* know beforehand how many actual new hits exist in System B. I need to `GET` 50,000 customers, from System A, each time I want to get the number of new hits.

### Solution B

> Send a `GET` request to system A, when a hit is produced by System B, overnight, to see if it's really a new hit that doesn't exist in System A.

#### Problem with this solution

Since the GET request is sent at the *time a hit is produced while checking the list* and not when the results are presented to the user there might be a mismatch. The user might have not tended to the results of System B and went ahead and manually entered a hit in System A. System B would still show that manually-entered hit from System A as a new hit in System's B morning results.

Is there a standard way of dealing with such problems?

### Details

- The 2 systems are built on Node.js/Express framework. I have build those systems myself so I have full control over them.
- The systems can communicate with each other using a REST API.
- I'd like to keep the 2 systems decoupled, honouring the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) - i.e System A just holds it's data, System B performs automatic screenings etc. I'd specifically like to avoid intertwining functionality between each system

Comment: Why can't system A just check to see if the hit from system B was produced manually in A?  If true, ignore the hit from B.

Comment: @Mike The morning results of the search are presented in system B - System A only receives via POST from System A.

Comment: So what is the impact if the user of B approves a hit, but unknown to the user it was already manually entered into A?

Comment: @Mike Not a big impact whatsoever, apart from the user having to screen a hit  in B that was entered thus already screened in A.

Comment: @nicholas-kyriakidesn Then maybe this is a non issue and you needn't spend time on it?

Comment: @Mike I'd say that if a computer can be used to shave off human-work time, then it should be put to work

Comment: The systems are tightly coupled whether you want it or not. It is part of the requirements.

Comment: Yeah that's true - I'm trying to keep them as decoupled *as possible* so System A can run without B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this with a combination of the following:

### HTTP Caching

To get the new hits, I send a `GET` request to grab the hits from system A. That `GET` request is cached for exactly 1 minute. Any subsequent requests are served from the cache instead of fetching over the network again.

There might be a mismatch in the *new hit count* but it's for very brief periods of time (when the cache is stale). I can certainly live with that

### Bypass cache when user focuses attention and get a fresh copy

When the user focuses on a particular hit (and is ready to transfer it), I perform a direct `GET` request again for that particular piece of data, bypassing the cache.

This ensures that when user is actually about to make a decision/operation on a hit, he is presented with the guaranteed, non-stale piece of data.